# C++ std::vector erasing element 0 throws exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, vector, element, erase

Sorry I can't provide code bc I don't have it.

My coworker (who has been with the company for a long time but doesn't appear to know what he's doing) claims that he has to do some weird stuff to remove elements from a vector.  He moves all the elements down a position (starting at the element that he wants to remove) then he'll remove the last element in the vector.  This sounds OK but very inefficient.  The standard library's std::vector::erase() should be able to handle this fine.

He does this because he claims that calling erase on element 0 gives random exceptions.

My question is what could cause this?  I am pretty sure that this is a thread-safety problem, but is there anything else that could cause it?

Please let me know...I'm new to C++.

Again, sorry for not being able to provide code.

Thanks,
Jbu

Comment: Without seeing the code, the answer is, "anything could be wrong with the code."  Get the code from your coworker and read through it; debug it, and see why it fails; if you have specific questions about some code, feel free to post the code here and undoubtedly someone will be able to help explain it.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis well the problem is that he's changed the code...since it was "not working"

Comment: @jbu - what exactly do you want here?  if you want a fix, get the code and post it. There are many ways the code could be broken, and it's not a productive use of anybody's time to guess.

Comment: isn't that a case when iterator becomes invalid after vector::erase() and, for example, someone still wants to increment it in the loop?

Comment: @jbu Tell him to change it back. There is almost certainly something wrong with his code, external to the erase. He is avoiding the symptom without fixing the cause, and it's going to come back and bite you guys.

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem on a minimal application. If it doesn't happen on a simple example, your friend is doing some weird stuff with the vector. What is he storing inside it? pointers?

Answer (score 5):

> ... calling erase on element 0 gives random exceptions.

No it doesn't.

That's all the answer you can expect without a lot more info about what he's actually doing.

Answer (score 2):

The only place where calling `erase` on element zero would be throwing exceptions would be cases where undefined behavior would have already been invoked. Most commonly, trying to erase element zero from an empty vector.

> This sounds OK but very inefficient.

Not really -- that's what `erase` is doing anyway. But it makes no sense to reimplement things the standard library already does for you.

Comment: Since (the standard version of) `std::vector::erase` requires using an iterator, it's also possible that an operation was performed on the vector that invalidated existing iterators.

Answer (score 1):

Without code it's difficult to say.  If `vector::size()` > 0, then erasing element 0 is completely valid.  It could be he's using an iterator to erase the 0th element, and the iterator has been invalidated somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of coworker's logic, I'd say your appraisal is accurate. 'Random exceptions' = 'undiagnosed bug due to misuse of the vector container'.

That said, the question is a bit pointless - if you can't provide the source, how can you get a definitive answer on what's wrong or otherwise?